# How can I efficiently duplicate Django sets?

Tags: django

I have a large data set of Course objects in a Django application.

```
courses = Course.objects.all()
```

I want to make a copy of these courses, except the new courses have different semester values. I have tried this code:

```
for course in courses:
   newCourse = course
   newCourse.semester = 'Spring 2012'
   newCourse.save()
```

However, this code is not working. It is just changing the semesters of the current courses.

How do I make a copy of the old data set efficiently? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation on [how Django knows whether to update or insert](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert) shows, if an object has a primary key value set, Django will always do an update on that object.

So the simple way to clone an object is to set its pk - usually `id` - to `None`. Then, when you save, Django will create a new object.

```
newCourse.semester = 'Spring 2012'
newCourse.id = None
newCourse.save()
```

Comment: this is a helpful trick. much easier (in most cases) than copying all the fields you want explicitly. Although as soon as i say that.... "explicit is better than implicit"?... just rambling...

Comment: Thanks. Since newCourse and course reference the same entity, I could also just do `course.semester='Spring 2012'`, `course.id` and then `course.save()` right? Just curious, which course is being saved when I do `course.save()`? The old course or both the old and new course?

Comment: Furthermore, how can I maintain a reference to the old course object?

Comment: Yes, both variables actually reference the exact same object. Once you set `id` to None on one, it is None on the other too. Neither of them retain a reference to the old object. You'll need to get it back from the database by keeping a reference to the ID in a separate variable and re-querying it from the db.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually creating a new object -- you're just pointing a variable to an existing record. Something like this would probably work:

```
for course in courses:
    newCourse = Course()                              # Create a new object
    newCourse.semester = 'Spring 2012'
    newCourse.otherProperty = course.otherProperty    # Copy other properties as needed
    newCourse.save()
```

You could even wrap this up in a method on the `Course` class:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    # Other stuff

    def copy(semester=None):
        new_course = Course()
        new_course.other_property = self.other_property
        if semester is not None:
            new_course.semester = semester
        return new_course
```

And just do:

```
for course in courses:
    newCourse = course.copy(semester='Spring 2012')
    newCourse.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you need to create a whole new list of courses, but they differ on `semester`, right?

Can you try `newCourse = copy.copy(course)`, because `newCourse = course` would create a reference to `course`, and when you modify that reference, you modify the object itself.